# Need to shift text to next line

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set MUMBAI-BHIWANRI to next Line(from Image), please tell me how can I fix it and make it look proper.
I am thankful for your answer.

Here is my full layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_trucknumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_from"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_from"
                android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_fromcity"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_tocity"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_to"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_to"
                android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_totalkms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_startDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_tentativeDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_currentLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_truckstatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_location_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_balloon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain your need more clearly?

Comment: Did you see my image which I had uploaded in this question

Comment: Yes friend please help.

Comment: there is no image...

Comment: This "to" information is coming from Gson service. I want to keep this "to" in next line after "From" for all locations, shown in image.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : Here is the image.

Comment: post your full xml file. @Prianshu

Comment: set the attribute for TextView: android:singleLine="false"

Comment: in your layout give orientation vertical..and give xml code full

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: not working this way.

Comment: From and To both textview is different?\

Comment: I am sorry to all, I am new in stackoverflow, I am pasting my whole xml file it is showing error,

Comment: which error you got?

Comment: Chirag : your post appears to have code which is not proparly formated" any other way to send code.

Comment: after past your code select code and press Ctrl+k after that you can post code.

Comment: chirag : please share your email address.will send there. if you can.

Comment: chirag: Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your need try below code.

Use weight for set layout properly.

I change some below property in your code. check comment in between code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_trucknumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_from"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/dashboard_from"
                    android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_fromcity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="BANGLORE-PEENYA"
                    android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_to"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/dashboard_to"
                    android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_tocity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="MUMBAI-BHIVANBI"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_totalkms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_startDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_tentativeDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_currentLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_truckstatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LobbTextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_location_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/landing_page_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_balloon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can place both textview horizontally and give equal weightage to both to maintain proper width for them. Alternatively you can create single textview and programmatically place 'to' in it when to and from city are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way , this is **solution i have tried**, this will bring *MUMBAI-BHIWANRI to next Line* check following file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item_fromcity_l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_fromcity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="From :"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edtlist_item_fromcity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="BANGLORE-PEENYA"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item_tocity_l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_tocity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="To :"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtlist_item_tocity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MUMBAI-BHIVANBI"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/total_km_l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_km"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Total Km :"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edttotal_km"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="150"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/startdate_l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startdate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Start date :"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtstartdate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="31/12/2015"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey why you use android:layout_weight="1" in `LinearLayout`?

Comment: to make these rows in proper sequence and as per requirement of @Prianshu it is required to set json value in TextView.@ChiragSavsani

Comment: I think there is no requirements for layout_weight in linearlayout.

Comment: I just gave answer what was requirement. do not forget to read official documentation. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html.

Comment: @ Chirag: Thank you so much brother.